# how to change the Visibility Property of button in the user control in the run time of the application?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a user control that have a multi buttons and In the application i use this user control on 3 windows,.. the edit button from the user control in this 3 window is Collapsed when the application run but i want to show edit button in all window when i open a specific window and Collapsed  all edit buttons again if  this window  Closed ...

**user control**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="Edit" x:Name="edit" Height="50"  Width="100" Margin="0" Click="Edit_Click" Visibility="{Binding editButtonVisibility}"/>
    <Button Content="Show History" x:Name="Personal" Height="50"  Width="100" Margin="0" Click="ShowHistory_Click" Visibility="{Binding ShowHistoryButtonVisibility}" />
    <Button Content="Show Customer" x:Name="Customer" Height="50"  Width="100" Margin="0" Click="ShowCustomer_Click" Visibility="{Binding ShowCustomerButtonVisibility}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

the code Behind for that user control add Dependency Properties for each of the Bindings above:

```
 public Visibility editButtonVisibility
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(editButtonVisibilityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(editButtonVisibilityProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for editButtonVisibility.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty editButtonVisibilityProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("editButtonVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));


public Visibility ShowHistoryButtonVisibility
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ShowHistoryButtonVisibilityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ShowHistoryButtonVisibilityProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowHistoryButtonVisibility.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowHistoryButtonVisibilityProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHistoryButtonVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));



public Visibility ShowCustomerButtonVisibility
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ShowCustomerButtonVisibilityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ShowCustomerButtonVisibilityProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowCustomerButtonVisibility.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCustomerButtonVisibilityProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShowCustomerButtonVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));
```

in that application

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:UI_UserControls="clr-namespace:Anet.UI.UserControls;assembly=Anet.UI.UserControls" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test" x:Class="test.Window1"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="308">
<Grid>
  <UI_UserControls: UserControl1 editButtonVisibility="Collapsed" ShowCustomerButtonVisibility="Collapsed" />
 </Grid>
```

and the same code in window 2 and window 3

i have try to add property changed call back , but didn't work

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty editButtonVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("editButtonVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(ProductionMenuChanged));


    private static void ProductionMenuChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        UserControlBtu = d as UserControl1;


            if (Window1.IsVisibleProperty == null)
            {
                UserControlBtu.edit.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else if (Window1.IsVisibleProperty != null)

            {
                 UserControlBtu.edit.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

    }
```

**P.S :**  the user control is not local .. it WPF User Control Library Project

Comment: Where did you define the dependency property? What is Window1?

Comment: _"but didn't work"_ -- _what_ didn't work? The _right_ way to do this is to bind the `editButtonVisibility` property directly to some shared data source that will control the property value. But without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you're having, along with a precise explanation of _what_ problem you're actually having, there's no useful way to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

found the problem. just do the following changes and it will work.

1.Give a name to your UserControl

```
X:name="AnyName"
```

2.Bind the button visibility property as following

```
Visibility="{Binding ElementName=AnyName, Path=editButtonVisibility}"
```

NOTE: replace AnyName with your usercontrol name.